# Finding equivalent capacitance between A and B,

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

Following is the question, asked is to find equivalent capacitance between A and B.

I've tried couple of times and getting 7/3 micro farad as the answer while the correct answer is 8/3 micro farads. Please explain the method to solve such questions.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of these problems are best done by first redrawing the circuit so that it is in a more accessible form.

[image]

The correct answer is $\frac 8 3 \;\mu$F.

Comment: It was always amazing to me in school (1) how often it just took redrawing the circuit to go "oh!" and (2) how often people didn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this strictly with adding capacitance in parallel and elastance in series. The 2uF is in parallel with the others. The two 1uF on the left are in parallel and the 1uF on the right is in series with the two on the left.

Comment: Doing that, we get 7/3 micro farads. But the answer given is 8/3 micro farads.

Comment: "we", a group effort?

Comment: Yes! Me and my friend.

Comment: But a homework problem?

Comment: Homework problem because it was in an assignment of our last batch and we were practicing those questions. (They had only answers with them, no solutions).

Answer (score 0):

Comment and Hint: The following figure may help, as long as you maintain all the connections this is the same circuit (will let you identify the capacitors). I get $8/3 \mu F$ [image]